# Человеко-понятные-url Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Всем привет. Такая ситуация, нужно настроить utm метки - в get запрос добавляется примерно такая информация: ?utm_source=news4&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=spring-summer.

При переходе на сайт по этим ссылкам - 404 ошибка.
Нужна помощь в настройке urlManager второго yii.
Нужно что-бы отрабатывал экшн без этих параметров. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Экшн в студию. Без кода сложно решить вопрос. По какой ссылке нет 404 ошибки?

Comment: @fedornabilkin
Прикол в том, что экшн здесь не решает ничего. В UrlManager жестко забиты пути. По всем ссылкам сайта с теми параметрами выбивает 404. Есть вариант написать заглушку, но документация бессильна.

Comment: Прикол в том, что как раз экшн может влиять на наличие 404, если он ожидает какой-то параметр. Разговор теряет смысл без кода. Надо смотреть на код экшена и правила UrlManager. Если экшн не ожидает каких-либо параметров, 404 не должна возникать.

Comment: @fedornabilkin
Спасибо) Экшн не ожидает параметров. В урлах жестко прописано:
'' => 'site/index',
'/user' => 'user/all-users'
Нету выражений такого плана:
''<controller:w+>/<action>' => '<controller>/<action>'
Я код не могу скинуть, там много) Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Так при чем тут эти параметры, если экшн не ожидает параметров и не отрабатывает без них (судя по вопросу)? Надо поэтапно, сначала экшн сделать, чтоб работал, потом прилепить параметры.

Comment: @fedornabilkin
Экшн отрабатывает без параметров, а с параметрами нет) Вот стек начала вызова:

yii\web\NotFoundHttpException in 
controllers/SiteController.php:206
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: app\controllers\SiteController->actionIndex()

Comment: Попробуйте в `urlManager` указать `'enableStrictParsing' => false`.